# Want a row of array values not a column

Tags: php, arrays

I've been coding all night so I've probably overlooked something, but my output looks like this:

```
Apartment Name #1                Apartment Name #1            
5.0                              5.0
 1                               1
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Apartment Name #1            5.0
```

Here is my class' method that is called:

```
public function apartmentList($zip = '')
    {
        $this->_zip = $zip;
        $list = array();
            $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT apartment.apartmentName, ratings.apartmentOverall, apartment.apartmentID
                    FROM apartment_information apartment, apartment_ratings ratings, user_user user
                    WHERE user.preferred_zip = :zip
                    ORDER BY ratings.apartmentOverall';

                    try{
                        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bindParam(":zip", $this->_zip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->execute();            
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
                        {
                            $list['apartmentName'] = $row['apartmentName'];
                            $list['apartmentOverall'] = $row['apartmentOverall'];
                            $list['apartmentID'] = $row['apartmentID'];
                            print_r($list);
                        }
                        return $list;

                   }
                   catch(PDOException $e)
                   {
                       echo $e->getMessage();
                   }

    }
```

And this is what it looks like when I call it:

```
include_once 'class.apartment.php';
                        $apartment = new Apartment($db);
                        $apartmentList = $apartment->apartmentList($_SESSION['zip']); 
                        foreach($apartmentList as $key => $value){
                        ?>
                        <li id="listing">
                            <a href="../template/apartment.php">
                            <span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span>
                                <span class="title">
                                    <?php echo $value; ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="rating">
                                    <?php echo $value; ?>
                                </span>
                            </a>    
                            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is just fine, it's a matter of css, really. But in case you want the exact formatting, make sure you wrap the list items (`li`) with a container (`ul`). It's kind of required anyway.

Also, remove the `id="listing"`. It's not unique node as id ought to be.

Comment: I have wrapped it in a container ul called listings (didn't include it in code though), and I changed the id to a class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the value twice, not the key and the value

Comment: Using $key turns it into
ApartmentName       Apartment Name#1
ApartmentOverallRating 5.0
ApartmentID         1